# Installing Tomcat as different user using yum

Tags: linux, tomcat, yum

I'm installing tomcat using yum package manager, but I want to run the service under different user (not tomcat).

Is there an easy way to do that on installation or am I always forced to change owner of all directories, service etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If tomcat is managed by systemd, you can add a custom file `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service.d/custom-user.conf` containing just the following lines

```
[Service]
User=myUser
```

For older OSes you should be able to do it by setting the `TOMCAT_USER` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat`.

This is an extra configuration of course. It's not possible to modify a rpm-provided configuration file without rebuilding the rpm. If you have an internal yum repository you can build a rpm package providing this file but I think the easier way is using a configuration management tool like ansible or saltstack.